# Best approach to generate unique order IDs for payment transactions?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, paytm

Currently, I am using simple linear addition for generating new order IDs like 110000, 110001, 110002... But in this approach anyone can calculate number of orders placing on my app. So I want to add a new approach in which order ID is Readable but not Understandable by the user. I want to use this in my android app. So what can I do to achieve this using some logic or 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Define "readable".

Comment: I am using firebase that creates unique and complex docid so I created a transaction collection to give me complex id for transaction purpose however, I use other random methods to create viewable/readable order ID for end users.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can generate non sequential unique id via calculation

`val idForUser = (9369712273 * dbId + 1365089121) % 999999937`

UPDATE: In order to automatically set the field value create trigger after insert and set idForUser value

```
CREATE TRIGGER id_generator
AFTER INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE table_name SET idForUser = (9369712273 * _id + 1365089121) % 999999937 WHERE _id = NEW._id;
END;
```